# SQL Sum of Value multiplied in Decode Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, decode

I have the following select statement in PL-SQL:

```
SELECT 
BATCH,
CURRENCY, 
SUM(DECODE(DEBIT_CREDIT,'D',-1,1) * VALUE)
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY BATCH, CURRENCY
HAVING SUM(DECODE(DEBIT_CREDIT,'D' ,-1,1) * VALUE)   <> 0;
```

This is coming from the following table:

```
Batch    Currency    Debit_Credit    Value
0001     EUR         D               200.00
0001     EUR         C               200.00
0002     USD         D               500.50
0002     USD         C               500.50
```

Basically what the select statement is doing is checking if the record is a credit or a debit. If it is a credit (has a value of C), the value of `value` remains positive, otherwise it turns to negative (by multiplying it by -1). At the end of the select statement showed in the example above there should be no results, since all records are reconciled.

However, this is not always happening. The issue seems to be in this line:

```
SUM(DECODE(DEBIT_CREDIT,'D',-1,1) * VALUE)
```

It seems that when multiplying a value by -1, the result doesn't always return the equivalent negative of the value.

Is this a known issue in PL-SQL? Has anyone else encountered it? Is there any way to go around it?

The only way I found to go around it was using the MINUS function as follows:

```
Select BATCH, CURRENCY, sum(VALUE) 
from MYTABLE
where DEBIT_CREDIT = 'C' 
group by BATCH, CURRENCY
MINUS 
Select BATCH, CURRENCY, sum(VALUE) 
from MYTABLE
where DEBIT_CREDIT = 'D' 
group by BATCH, CURRENCY;
```

The result of this query works correctly and returns an empty value as a result. However I would like to find a better way to go around this.

Any help is appreciated :)

**EDIT:**

Let's say I run the query: `Select BATCH, CURRENCY, DEBIT_CREDIT, decode(DEBIT_CREDIT, 'D', -1,1) * VALUE from myTable` where BATCH = '0034' and CURRENCY = 'OMR'. The result is the one below

```
Batch    Currency    Debit_Credit    Value
0034     OMR         C               0.01
0034     OMR         D               -0.01
```

So far so good.

However, If I add the sum function to the decode as mentioned in the first PL-SQL statement, I get the following result:

```
Batch    Currency    SUM(DECODE(DEBIT_CREDIT,'D',-1,1) * VALUE)
0034     OMR         0.01
```

In reality I should get a 0 as the negative value should eliminate the positive one.

Comment: Could you show us the rows where it does not work correctly? DECODE is a pretty straightforward function. Only if you have a negative VALUE for 'D' it won't return a negative result. P.S.: It has nothing to do with PL/SQL. Also, MINUS is not the same as - .. There is different logic behind it.

Comment: So could you give the example of rows where DECODE is not working as expected?

Comment: Could you please create reproducible example on sqlfiddle.com? With table DDL and insert scripts. Now it looks like you have problem in another place (type conversion, incorrect data, etc.)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with PL/SQL, which is the procedural language for writing stored procedures etc. It's pure SQL. Please change the title and the tags.

Comment: Do you have only 'C' and 'D' or any other values. ALso, are you sure all the records in value column is positive ?

Comment: In your edited example you have -1 and 1 in different positions: `decode(DEBIT_CREDIT, 'D', 1,-1)` and `SUM(DECODE(DEBIT_CREDIT,'D',-1,1) * VALUE)`. Could that be the case?

Comment: OK, I can't repeat the problem. Which means that you either have the same mistake in your actual decode or we need an actual data: https://pastebin.com/raw/16s44H3B

Comment: Also, what type is the column DEBIT_CREDIT? Can you show us the result of `desc mytable`?

Comment: Sorry, the VALUE column.. :D

Comment: Here is a SQLFiddle with your problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4fd9a1/3 Everything works as expected from what I understand. Could you reproduce the problem there?

Comment: multiply by -1 is working here. http://rextester.com/RCXQ94516

Comment: Does this behave the same? `SUM(CASE WHEN DEBIT_CREDIT = 'D' THEN -VALUE ELSE VALUE END)`

Comment: As an aside, really, if you're looking for amounts that directly contra off against each other, you shouldn't be using their sums, as that contras the summation. If you have two credits of 1000 and a debit of 2000, then overall your balance is 0, but these records don't reconcile with each other directly (unless you're making that rule up, that the sum of debits and the sum of credits may contra).. Perhaps joining the table to itself looking for mismatches via a full outer join would be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE debit_credit = 'D') d
   FULL OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE debit_credit = 'C') c
   ON
     d.batch = c.batch and 
     d.currency = c.currency and
     d.value = c.value
WHERE
     c.batch IS NULL OR d.batch IS NULL;
```

This will look for debits and credits that don't directly contra each other, even though the summations might. It might also help you realise what the data problem is that affects your decode method